# Memoir: How to make `\newfootnoteseries` with multiple paragraphs?

Tags: footnotes, memoir, paragraphs, starred-version

I have two levels of footnotes, one for regular footnotes and one for special editor's footnotes. I would like to put a longer text in an editor's footnote with two paragraphs, however this does not work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newfootnoteseries{E}
\renewcommand\thefootnoteE{\textcolor{red}{\Roman{footnoteE}}}
\let\editornote=\footnoteE

\begin{document}

Text%
\footnote{Footnote paragrah 1.
% -- removing this is fine
Footnote paragraph 2.}%
\editornote{Editor paragraph 1.
% -- removing this breaks
Editor paragraph 2.}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error when removing the second `%`:

```
Runaway argument?
{\rule \z@ \footnotesep \ignorespaces {\@nameuse {foottextfontE}Edito\ETC.
./editornotes.tex:17: Paragraph ended before \@makefntextE was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.17 Editor paragraph 2.}

?
```

Strangely, multiple paragraphs work fine in the regular footnote.

Comment: If I understand "long" commands correctly, it seems that the `\footnoteE` that `\newfootnoteseries{E}` creates is "starred" --- can I override that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `\newfootnoteseries{E}` creates a "short" `\@makefntextE` which is the cause of the problem. I have tested with a modified `memoir.cls` locally and it seems to work, but I am unsure what the process is now. Is there a repo to submit patches to?

I also cannot guarantee that it won't mess with other parts of memoir, as I am unfamiliar with its internal workings.

Below, a patch for version v3.7h (2018/12/12)

```
$ diff -p /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls memoir.cls 
*** /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls  Wed Dec 12 22:24:10 2018
--- memoir.cls  Fri May 17 15:41:06 2019
***************
*** 9362,9368 ****
    \m@makefootfootmark{#1}%                       -> \footfootmark#1
    \m@makemakefootmark{#1}%                       -> \makefootmark#1
    \m@makefootmarkstyle{#1}%                      -> \footmarkstyle#1
!   \@namedef{@makefntext#1}##1{\@nameuse{makefootmark#1} ##1}%
    \m@make@footstart{#1}%                         -> \@footstart#1
    \m@make@footgroup{#1}%                         -> \@footgroup#1
    \expandafter\newinsert\csname @mpfootins#1\endcsname% -> \@mpfootins#1
--- 9362,9368 ----
    \m@makefootfootmark{#1}%                       -> \footfootmark#1
    \m@makemakefootmark{#1}%                       -> \makefootmark#1
    \m@makefootmarkstyle{#1}%                      -> \footmarkstyle#1
!   \@namelongdef{@makefntext#1}##1{\@nameuse{makefootmark#1} ##1}%
    \m@make@footstart{#1}%                         -> \@footstart#1
    \m@make@footgroup{#1}%                         -> \@footgroup#1
    \expandafter\newinsert\csname @mpfootins#1\endcsname% -> \@mpfootins#1
```

I will hold off on accepting my own answer for a couple weeks, to see if a better one comes along.

Comment: I think you have the correct idea. I've added this to my bugs list for memoir (pressed on time at the momemnt so no time frame). Short just means that new paragraphs (blank lines or `\par`) cannot be used in the argument. `\newcommand` are long, `\newcommand*`  are not. `\def` is also not long.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Let me know if you need anything from my end :)

Comment: It is now fixed in my development version. It is the fix you provided. BTW I'd never go in and fix the class directly by hand in a situation like this, I'd just copy the problematic construction into your preamble and fix it where before you use it. Currently no idea when I'm going to release the next memoir version

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% \newfootnoteseries{E}
% \renewcommand\thefootnoteE{\textcolor{red}{\Roman{footnoteE}}}
% \let\editornote=\footnoteE

\newcounter{editorfn}

\makeatletter
\def\editornote{%
    \refstepcounter{editorfn}
    \xdef\@thefnmark{\roman{editorfn}} \@footnotetext
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text%
\footnote{Footnote paragrah 1.\\
% -- removing this is fine
Footnote paragraph 2.}%
\editornote{Editor paragraph 1.\\
% -- removing this breaks
Editor paragraph 2.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't show the footnotemark for the editornote anywhere that I can see

Comment: In that case, I suggest you to change the line
`\xdef\@thefnmark{\roman{editorfn}} \@footnotetext`

by
`\xdef\@thefnmark{\roman{editorfn}}$^\mathrm{\@thefnmark}$ \@footnotetext`

If you prefer subscript instead of superscript, change the `^` by `_`